# Run time for CPAP on 18V-240V inverter

Tags: inverter

How long should a 240V 45W appliance run on on an inverter connected to an 18V 5Ah (90Wh) battery?

The appliance is a CPAP connected to a Ryobi 18v lithium battery inverter.

Comment: 2 hours at a guess. There’s too many unknowns to give an accurate answer. Charge the battery and run the unit. Time how long it runs for. Most modern cpap machines run from 12V - doing this cuts out a lot of losses.

Comment: Too much unknown. 90 Wh/45w = 2h BUT, inverter efficiency, inadvisability of running battery to absolute limit (but LiIon is not bad), true CPAP drain in use (really constant 45W or cycling or varies with user settings or ...?), temperature effects if any, more. || ABOUT 2 hours seems a good start. Could be quite a lot more and may be somewhat less. Unlinkely to be under 1 hour and probably not under 1.5 hours.

Comment: Run the appliance through a Kill-a-watt or local equivalent and see what power it REALLY takes.

Answer (score 1):

\$ \frac {Wh} W \times eff \$ gives you the run time in hours. A small inverter may have an efficiency of 60 to 80%, I'd reckon and you don't really want to run your batteries to flat.

Answer (score 1):

Too much is unknown to do more than make an informed guess.

90 Wh/45w = 2 hours
BUT consider -

- User settings
- Inverter efficiency,
- Inadvisability of running battery to absolute limit (but LiIon is not bad),
- What is the true CPAP drain in use
  (really constant 45W or cycling or varies with user settings or ...?),
- Temperature effects if any,
- Possibly altitude and even weather (pressure changes) effects
- More ... .

So

ABOUT 2 hours seems a good start.
It could be quite a lot more
and may be somewhat less.

It seems unlikely to be under 1 hour
and probably not under 1.5 hours.